# Pandas - Formatting Column chart label

Tags: pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I am trying to create a column chart using Pandas.

I have a DataFrame in the below format.

```
Week, Percent_Sold
1,13
2,15
3,44
```

I am trying to get a column chart using the below code:

```
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column'})
chart.add_series({'name': 'Sales Percent', 'categories': f'=\'sales\'!$A$11:$A$13',
                                     'values': f'=\'sales\'!$B$11:$B$13',
                                     'data_labels': {'value': True, 'num_format': '0%'}})
```

The above works well, however I see the numbers in chart get converted from 13 to 1300% but rather I am trying to display 13% in the chart. How could I modify the `add_series` method to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `13.00%` to be displayed:
 `'num_format':'0.00##\%'`

Else if you want `13%` (without any decimals), then: `'num_format':'##\%'`

> Got answer from this topic: [Percentage format multiplies cell value by 100](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/570)

**PS:** It's more related to *xlsxwriter* than pandas

Comment: I am able to display the number with the formatting `%`. I am trying to add the `%` symbol next to the number, doing so changes the number from 13 to 1300%

Comment: it fails as it throws an error `name 'f' is not defined`